# Changing background color based on another View in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have WheelView and WheelBackground, first one is a group of rounded rectangles that i rotate with a drag gesture based on degrees, second one is the background, changing its color based on degrees too, i would like to have these background colors like my squares, for example red square, red back, green square green back and so on...but i don't know how to change these colors based on degrees, any suggestions?

This is my code:

```
struct WheelBackground: View {
    @Binding var degree: Double
    
    var body: some View {
        Color.orange
            .opacity(0.4)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .hueRotation(Angle(degrees: degree))
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var degree = -90.0

var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            WheelBackground(degree: $degree)
            
            WheelView(degree: $degree)
                .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: degree))
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Show your WheelView. I don't see your wheel view here.

Comment: That calculation (decision making) should be somewhere outside of both views, eg. in view model, and result (current color depending on degree) injected into both views.

Comment: What calculation are you talking about? i applied .huerotation(Angle) modifier that takes degrees as a parameter

Comment: @tail wheelView is not involved, i have to work on WheelBackground, it put it only to better explain the gif on imgur

Comment: I am pretty sure you don't know what are you talking about. If the color of your WheelView changes based on degree value, WheelBackground would behave the same with the same logic. You are binding $degree to both WheelBackground and WheelView.

Comment: @tail degree in wheelview is for detecting the drag gesture and define whether the user swiped left or right, while in wheelbackground it's involved in changing background colors thanks to .huerotation modifier

Comment: anyway i'd like to post wheelview code but it's too long

Comment: All I wanted to know is what type of color or number of color you use with your Square. You can easily bind color from the WheelView to WheelBackground and make both of these views use the same color at the same time.

Comment: i'm adding wheelView code rn

Answer (score 0):

Refer to your question and comment, since you could not provide the code of WheelView(), this is the closest replicated view that I can make to demonstrate the solution for your problem. This code focuses on the logic that you want your `background` and `square` to have the same color whenever the color changes.

Try this below code:

```
struct TestContentView: View {
let allColors = [Color.red, Color.blue, Color.green, Color.orange, Color.purple, Color.pink]
@State var color = Color.red
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        WheelBackgroundExample(color: $color)
        VStack {
            WheelViewExample(color: $color)
            Button("change") {
                color = allColors[Int.random(in: 0...5)]
            }
            .foregroundColor(.black)
        }
        
    }
}
}

struct WheelViewExample: View {
@Binding var color: Color
var body: some View {
    Rectangle()
        .fill(color)
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
        .border(.black)
}
}

struct WheelBackgroundExample: View {
@Binding var color: Color
var body: some View {
    Rectangle()
        .fill(color)
}
}
```